# How to delete an object that is referenced from other objects?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

How can I delete an object that is referenced from other objects? Example:

```
Person person = new Person();
Payment payment = new Payment();
payment.setReceiverOfPayment(person);

dao.delete(person);
```

Classes:

```
class Person {

}

class Payment {
    //optional
    @OneToOne
    private Person receiverOfPayment;
}
```

Now, if I delete object person, I'm getting an exception:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action; 
FK_PAYMENT_RECEIVEROFPAYMENT_ID table: PAYMENT
```

This is of course due to the fact that some payments may still have a reference to person.

Would I have to iterate all my payments in the DB before I delete a person and clear the references manually? Or is there any cascading (or similar) option that can handle this automatically?

Comment: You don't have a bidirectional relationship, so you cannot use JPA's Cascade.

Comment: What would I have to change in the model above then to profit from JPA cascade?

Comment: A `@ManyToMany` to a `List<Payment` might work, but the Cascade is generated by application code, not database. You will get an update request (if the FK can be null) for each Payment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add payment field to your Person object. You need a bidirectional relationship to use Cascade.

Something like this :

```
@Entity
public class Payment {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="myColumn")
    private Person receiverOfPayment;
}

@Entity
public class Person {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="receiverOfPayment")
    private Payment payment;
}
```

Depending on what you want, a ManyToOne might be more relevant. More info in [Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association).